# convert spring xml configuration to java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, configuration

I am not able to convert following piece of configuration to java configuration.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
      <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
      <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
      <property name="locations">
        <list>
          <value>classpath*:META-INF/spring/environments/${XXX_env}/*.properties</value>
          <value>file:/etc/XXX/database.properties</value>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

In above example, XXX_env is an environment variable. For example,

```
export XXX_env=dev
```

How do I convert this to Spring Java Configuration? Here is my attempt:

```
@Bean
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer() throws IOException {
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer props = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
    props.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    props.setSystemPropertiesMode(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE);
    Resource[] locations;
    PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver classPathResources = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    locations = classPathResources.getResources("classpath*:META-INF/spring/environments/"+env()+ "/*.properties");
    props.setLocations(locations);
    Resource location = new FileSystemResource("/etc/XXX/database.properties");
    props.setLocation(location);
    return props;
}

private String env(){
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    return env.get("XXX_env");
}

@Value("${database.password}")
private String databasePassword;

@Value("${database.url}")
private String databaseUrl;

@Value("${database.username}")
private String databaseUsername;

@Value("${database.driverClassName}")
private String databaseDriverClassName;
```

Comment: Why are you not able, what is the problem?

Comment: Let me update the question.

Comment: Is the problem here with the `env()`? You can also use Spring's `Environment` which is injectable.

Comment: I think the problem is with regular expression matching when loading *.properties from a directory under classpath.

Answer (score 0):

suggestion:

put

```
Resource location = new FileSystemResource("/etc/XXX/database.properties");
```

in locations array then `setLocations(locations)` instead of `setLocation(location)`.